# the += operator on immutable Set

Tags: scala

When i do e.g:

```
var airlines = Set("Qantas", "JetStar", "Air NZ")
airlines += "Virgin"
```

airlines is an immutable Set.

`+=` is not defined on the immutable Set trait.

So is `+=` a built-in operator in scala? I mean how does scala know to reassign airlines with a new `set("Qantas", "JetStar", "Air NZ", "Virgin")` ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If an operator ending with `=` (e.g. `+=`) is used but not defined on a class, the Scala compiler will desugar this into e.g.

```
airlines = airlines + "Virgin"
```

or, for `++=`, we’d have

```
airlines ++= airlines
```

desugared into

```
airlines = airlines ++ airlines
```

Of course, as [dmeister notes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7711481/the-operator-on-immutable-set/7711634#7711634), this will only compile if that new expression makes sense. For example, if we deal with `var`s.

See [Scala Reference §6.12.4 Assignment Operators](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf)
<sup>(`<=` , `>=` and `!=` are excluded as special cases, as are patterns also starting with `=`.)</sup>

Comment: do you mean '+=' ? or just '=' ?

Comment: I mean ending with `=`, so this is true for `+=` or `-=` or `++=`. (`<=` , `>=` and `!=` are excluded as special cases, as are patterns also starting with `=`.)

Answer (score 3):

The `+=` operator creates a new immutable set containing `"Virgin"` and assigns the new set to the `airlines` variable. Strictly speaking the existing set object has not changed, but the set objected the airlines variable points to.

Therefore it is important for this to work that airlines is a `var` variable and not a `val`, because you cannot reassign to a `val` variable.