# Where is the `++=` operator defined for a scala immutable list?

Tags: scala

How is the `++=` being evaluated in the code below? The `++=` operator is being applied to a class that is explicitly defined as an immutable list, which does not have the `++=` operator. `x ++= y` appears to have the same behavior as `x = x ++ y`, but I cannot find where this behavior is coming form. What is happening here? (and where is it documented?)

```
object ListConcatenation extends App {
  var list = scala.collection.immutable.List[Int](1)
  println(list)

  list = list ++ scala.collection.immutable.List[Int](2)
  println(list)

  // This operator does not exist on the List class, but has the same behavior as the operation above.
  list ++= scala.collection.immutable.List[Int](3)
  println(list)
}
```

**Output**

```
List(1)
List(1, 2)
List(1, 2, 3)
```

Comment: Isn't it actually two operators? The unary `var++` and an assignment with `=`?

Comment: Actually `list = list ++ rest`.

Comment: http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/06-expressions.html#assignment-operators

Comment: @Laurel if I put a space between the ++ and the = operator, then is does not compile.

Comment: @som-snytt Thanks, that is exactly what I was looking for. If you put that in an answer I will accept it.

Comment: Dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/q/7711481/1296806

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> x ++= y appears to have the same behavior as x = x ++ y

It does.

> but I cannot find where this behavior is coming form.

It's built into the language. When `x op= y` can't be interpreted as a calling the method `op=` (because no such method exists in `x`'s class or any class that it can be implicitly converted to), it's instead interpreted as calling the method `op` and an assignment.

> (and where is it documented?)

In Scala's language specification, [section 6.12.4](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/06-expressions.html#assignment-operators):

> #### Assignment Operators
>
> An assignment operator is an operator symbol (syntax category op in Identifiers) that ends in an equals character “=”, with the exception of operators for which one of the following conditions holds:
>
> 1. the operator also starts with an equals character, or
> 2. the operator is one of (`<=`), (`>=`), (`!=`).
>
> Assignment operators are treated specially in that they can be expanded to assignments if no other interpretation is valid.
>
> Let's consider an assignment operator such as `+=` in an infix operation `l += r`, where `l`, `r` are expressions. This operation can be re-interpreted as an operation which corresponds to the assignment
>
> ```
> l = l + r
> ```
>
> except that the operation's left-hand-side `l` is evaluated only once.
>
> The re-interpretation occurs if the following two conditions are fulfilled.
>
> 1. The left-hand-side `l` does not have a member named `+=`, and also cannot be converted by an implicit conversion to a value with a member named `+=`.
> 2. The assignment `l  = l + r` is type-correct. In particular this implies that l refers to a variable or object that can be assigned to, and that is convertible to a value with a member named `+`.